# Convert Char *ptr to Char *ptrArray[] to use in qsort

Tags: c

Working on using qsort.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma once

int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b);


int main()
{   
   int count = 0;
   char * randomStr = "sdjsn9i3ms;sa;'smsn92;w;''[w0p4;dsmsdf";
   char * charArray[] =
    {"s","d","j","s","n","9","i","3","m","s",";","s","a",";","'","s","m","s","n"
    ,"9","2",";","w",";","'","'","[","w","0","p","4",";","d","s","m","s","d","f"};

   size_t strings_len = sizeof(charArray) / sizeof(char *);
   /*void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, 
    size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));*/

    qsort(charArray, strings_len, sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);

    qsort(randomStr, strings_len, sizeof(char *), cstring_cmp);

    // Pause at command prompt
    system("pause");

    return 0;

} // Close function Main

int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

So obviously my second qsort is not working. whether that's based on my cstring_cmp function that goes into my qsort not being able to support the base i give it or because my base is not formatted to correctly input into the qsort is a mystery to me.

My Question is how do I convert char * randomStr to char * charArray[] dynamically, during runtime, on the fly, or whatever cool phrase you can come up with. I've searched around a lot and maybe I was just not asking the right question, so I'm coming to you guys for some real question answering power.

Just starting C so if you please try not to fry my brain with your answers me and my brain would appreciate it.

My end goal here is to convert randomStr to a format of charArray, qsort it then convert it back to the randomStr format so i can do some find and replace things I have set up already.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you use `char *randomStr = "Stuff"` [you can't change it](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html), it's undefined behavior. Second, try this:

```
int
cmp_fry_brain(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *((const char *)a) - *((const char *)b);
}

/* This is equivalent to the one above (the compiler will likely emit the
 * exact same code).
 */
int
cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *x = a;
    const char *y = b;

    return *x - *y;
}

int
main()
{
    char str[] = "This is the end";
    qsort(str, strlen(str), 1, cmp_fry_brain);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the brainless `cmp()`?  Since you don't show it in use, it might not be obvious that it's the same as the brain-fried version.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fair enough, I added a comment :-)